# Mybatis - Inherited properties not being mapped

Tags: java, generics, mybatis

I have two classes where one inherits the other. I'm trying to map my resultSet to the subclass and Mybatis is ignoring the properties on the superclass (Setters also on the superclass)

Code is as below:

```
public class CocTreeNode extends CocBean implements TreeNode<CocTreeNode> {

  private String level1, level2;

  public void setLevel1(String level1){...}
  public void setLevel2(String level2){...}

  public String getLevel1(){...}
  public String getLevel1(){...}

}

public class CocBean {

  protected String name;
  protected Double volume;

  public void setName(String name){...}
  public void setVolume(Double volume){...}

  public String getName(){...}
  public Double getVolume(){...}

}
```

My resultMap is -

```
<resultMap id="simpleRow" type="CocTreeNode">
  <id property="level1" column="LEVEL1"/>
  <id property="level2" column="LEVEL2"/>
  <result property="name" column="NAME"/>
  <result property="volume" column="VOLUME"/>
</resultMap>
```

The resulting CocTreeNode objects are populated with 'level1' and 'level2' attributes but not 'name' and 'volume'.

I have tried using extends but that didn't make any difference.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure , your sql statements work fine?

Comment: Yes. Copying CocBean(Superclass)'s code into CocTreeNode results in all the properties being set properly.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to use *extends* in your simpleRow resultmap to extend properties from CocBean's resultmap:

```
<resultMap id="CocBeanResult" type="CocBean">
    <result property="name" column="NAME"/>
    <result property="volume" column="VOLUME"/>
</resultMap>

<resultMap id="simpleRow" type="CocTreeNode" extends="CocBeanResult">
    <result property="level1" column="LEVEL1"/>
    <result property="level2" column="LEVEL2"/>
</resultMap>
```

Comment: I'm glad you find my answer helpful. You should accept it then.

Comment: My requirements have changed and I made the super class abstract. Extends attribute doesn't seem to work now.

Comment: If you just changed the super class to asbtract, it should definitely work. Post here those beans and both result maps.